# Update TextView in a Widget on button press

Tags: java, android, android-widget

i'm creating a simple widget with a simple input (uses another Activity to get a value) and a text view which should display this input.

I am a bit stuck however on how the text view should be updated within the widget.

currently i have my OnUpdate:

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds) {
    theContext = context;
    for(int i=0; i<appWidgetIds.length; i++){

        int currentWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, inputActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_main);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingIntent);


        views.setTextViewText(R.id.textView, textToShow);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(currentWidgetId, views);

        Toast.makeText(context, "widget added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

this calls my external main_activity when the button is pressed, but when the external Activity is submitted, **what is the best way to update the text view within the Widget to show this text?**

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use broadCast can pass params
external Activity sendbroadcast;

```
//externalActivity
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(...);
this.sendBroadCast(intent)
```

in Main_activity regist a receiver, hope help you.